Deducing number of arguments in a parameter pack
In C++, I'm trying to figure out how one can deduce the size of the parameter pack for a function, and further how one can deduce the number of parameters of a particular type (e.g. ints)
template<int N, int N_ints, typename... Ts> 
void foo(Ts... ts){ 
   ...
}


So that I could call it like

foo(1,2,'3')


and that would be the same as

foo<3,2>(1,2,'3') 


I couldnt even get the basic problem to work, i.e.

template<int N, class... Ts>
std::array<int, N> foo(Ts... ts)
{

    constexpr int n = sizeof...(ts);
    std::array<int, n> out; 
    return out;
}


int main()
{
    auto a = foo(1, 2, 3, '4', 5);
    return 0;
}

fails because it can't deduce N.

why do you think you need N in the template parameter list? I mean you already know that it is sizeof...(ts) no need to have it in the list

number of ints in the front can be counted too. No need to have it as free parameter either

Perhaps trailing return type would work, as in template<typename... Ts> auto foo(Ts... ts) -> std::array<int, sizeof...(ts)> { ... }?

The tittle does not correspond the question body. You know the size of the parameter pack.

And depending on C++ standard you use, then perhaps full return type deduction could work as well: template<typename... Ts> auto foo(Ts... ts) { return std::array<int, sizeof...(ts)>(); }?

template<class... Ts> std::array<int, sizeof...(Ts)> foo(Ts... ts) works in all C++ since 11.

i tried to provide an answer, but similar to others I am not entirely sure what the confusion is. You say you cannot deduce N but at the same time you do deduce it  via constexpr int n = sizeof...(ts);

You are making this too complicated by adding degrees of freedom that are not actually present. The information on the size of the pack and the  number of occurences of int in the pack is already in the pack.
#include <iostream>

template <typename T,typename... Ts>
struct count {
    static const unsigned value = (std::is_same_v<T,Ts> + ...);
};

template<typename... Ts> 
void foo(Ts... ts){ 
    std::cout << "num params : " << sizeof ...(Ts) << "\n";
    std::cout << "num ints : " << count<int,Ts...>::value << "\n";
}

int main() {
    foo(1,2,3.0);
}

I wasn't sure if you want to count all occurences of int in the pack or only the leading ones. I chose the former. Purists may claim that a static_cast<bool> would be more clear, but I think I can get a away with an implicit conversion here.

If for some reason you need to use the template arguments as in your example, you can still do that:
template<typename... Ts> 
auto foo(Ts... ts){ 
    return foo_impl<sizeof ...(Ts),count<int,Ts...>::value>(ts...);
}


Thank you! I am still learning C++ so this is very helpful. I am able to use what you suggested to get my case of a std::array working https://godbolt.org/z/77WvbqzPc.

(sorry for the spam, but I wasn't able to edit my previous comment)
However, I am not able to get a slightly more complex case working, and it gives different errors with GCC and clang! Any ideas?
gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/o7nW7h7qr
clang: https://godbolt.org/z/58oddnxd1

@VarchasGopalaswamy {1,3} does not have a type that could be deduced. And I also do not understand what you want to happen. Gccs error message is somewhat confusing, but clang is quite to the point.

I'm trying to see if I can emulate FORTRAN's array slicing syntax with C++. Ideally, it would be possible to do something like a(1, 2, 1:5:2) to take the corresponding slices, but I am guessing that's not possible since the : character doesnt seem to be something we are allowed to overload in any context. I was hoping it might instead be possible to do a(1, 2, {1,5,2}), since that's nice and terse, but I'm running into this template deduction issue.

I know I can do a(1, 2, std::array{1,5,2}) and it seems to work (see https://godbolt.org/z/ETTn8x761), but it would be great if I didn't have to write std::array everywhere...
Regardless, I appreciate the help so far and I'll accept the answer

@VarchasGopalaswamy the issue you face now it totally unrelated to the question  here. You can open a follow up quesiton
